# Dynamically set XML namespace in Jackson

Tags: xml, jackson, xml-namespaces

I currently have this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace = "some-ns", localName = "queryResult")
public class QueryResult {
    ...
}
```

Now I need to make `"some-ns"` configurable through a config file (i.e. set in runtime).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom `AnnotationIntrospector`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.JacksonXmlAnnotationIntrospector;

public class MyJacksonXmlAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonXmlAnnotationIntrospector
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public PropertyName findRootName(AnnotatedClass ac) {
        PropertyName pn = super.findRootName(ac);
        return pn.withNamespace("custom"); 
    }
}
```

and then pass it to the jackson mapper:

```
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new MyJacksonXmlAnnotationIntrospector());
    xmlMapper.writeValue(System.out, new QueryResult());
```